# Identity Functions Proof

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Claim:** Let $f:A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$ be functions. Prove that if $g \circ f$ and $f \circ g$ are identity functions, then $f$ is bijective.

**Attempt:** An identity function is a function such that $h(x)=x$, or $h(\text{something})=\text{something}$.

Hence, we have that $g(f(x))=f(x)$ and $f(g(x))=g(x)$.

To show that $f$ is injective, we want to show that $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies x_1=x_2$. For this problem, we have that $f(g(x_1))=f(g(x_2)) \implies g(x_1)=g(x_2)$, so $f$ is injective.

To show that $f$ is surjective, we want to show that $\forall y \in A,\,\exists\,x \in A$ such that $f(g(x))=y$.

At this point I am stuck. I get that $f(g(x))=g(x)=y$ since $f \circ g$ is an identity function. Is this the end of the proof? I feel like I missed something.

Comment: You’re stuck because you are rather presupposing that $f\circ g$ being the identity means $ f$ is the identity. So for instance your injectivity proof should have run like $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies g\circ f(x_1)=g\circ f(x_2)$ and $g\circ f$ being the identity finishes it. You can easily work out surjectivity with this correct understanding.

Comment: Ah, it does make more sense to start with $f(x)$ and then manipulate it from there. I will go with that approach.

Comment: You biggest mistake is that if $h= g\circ f$ is an identity function the $g(f(x)) = x$  (!not! $f(x))$ and $f(g(x)) = x$  (!not! $g(x)$).  Also note $g(f(x)) = x$ assume $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and the range of $g$; that is $A$ .but $f(g(x)) = x$ assumes $x$ is in the domain of $g$ and the range of $f$; that is $B$.  So $g\circ f: A\to A$ so that $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in A$.  And $f\circ g:B\to B$ so that $f(g(y)) = y$ for all $y \in B$.  .. Does the question make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hence, we have that g(f(x))=f(x) and f(g(x))=g(x).

No!

You have that $g(f(x)) = x$  and $f(g(y)) = y$.

$g$ is *not* the identity function!  $g\circ f$ is! And $f$ is not the identity function! $f\circ g$ is!

And note that $x \in A$ so $f(x) \in B$ so $g(f(x)) \in A$. And $y\in B$ so $g(y) \in A$ so $f(g(y)) \in B$.

======

Youf proof if injection doesn't work.  $f(g(x_1)) = f(g(x_2)) \implies x_1 = x_2$ but it does *not* imply $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$ (unless we *assume* ahead of time that $f$ is injective).

Instead use that if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2))$ (that's true for *all* functions.  If $a = b$ then $g(a) = g(b)$).  And as $g\circ f$ is the identity $g(f(x_1)) = x_1$ and $g(f(x_2)) = x_2$ so $f(x_1) = f(x_2)\implies x_1 = x_2$ and so $f$ is injective.

.....

"To show that f is surjective, we want to show that ∀y∈A,∃x∈A such that f(g(x))=y."

Not at all!

You want to show that $\forall y \in B, \exists x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$.

" I get that f(g(x))=g(x)=y"

Not at all!  $f(g(x)) \ne g(x)$ because $f(k)\ne k$ because $f$ is not that identity function.  $f\circ g$ is the identity function so $f(g(x)) = x$.

Also if $x \in A$  and $g: B\to A$ we can't have $g(x)$.  It's not defined unless $x \in B$ as well as in $A$.

Maybe you need to realize is that $A$ and $B$ are different sets.

You have $f: A\to B$ and $g: B\to A$ so $f\circ g: B\to A\to B$ and that's an identity function *on the set $B$* so that for all $y \in B$ then $f(g(y)) = y$.  And $g\circ f: A\to B\to A$ and that's an identity function *on the set $A$* so that for all $x \in A$ then $g(f(x)) = x$.

.......

So to prove $f$ is surective you need that for all $y\in B$ there is an $x\in A$ so that $f(x) = y$.  Now $f\circ g$ is the identity function so $f(g(y)) = y$.  And $g(y) \in A$.  So if we let $x = g(y)$ then $f(x) = f(g(y)) = y$.  That's it.  $f$ is surjective.